# how to save extracted data to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.6, extract

I have a text file with the following content

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the third line
this is the fourth line and contains the word fox.
```

The goal is to write a code that reads the file, extracts the line with
the word `fox` in it and saves that line to a new text file.Here is the code I have so far

```
import os
import re

my_absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with open('textfile', 'r') as helloFile:

    for line in helloFile:

        if re.findall("fox",line):

            print(line.strip())
```

This code prints the result of the parsed text but thats not really what I want it to do. Instead I would like the code to create a new text file with that line. Is there a way to accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
with open('textfile', 'r') as in_file, open('outfile', 'a') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if 'fox' in line:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Here I've opened the `outfile` in append (`a`) mode to accomodate multiple writes. And also used the `in` (`str.__contains__`) check for substring existence (Regex is absolutely overkill here).

Comment: Third line should be `if 'fox' in line:`

Comment: A pythonic solution, upvote for pointing out regex is overkill.

Comment: thank you @heemayl. I know regex was not necessary but I am using this as a precursor to something a little more complicated.